# When I install ember and execute ember server. appear this: node_modules appears empty. I'm working on PC win10 x64

Tags: javascript, ember.js, npm, ember-cli, npm-install

Command console:

```
C:\Users\Documents\emberjs>ember server
node_modules appears empty, you may need to run `npm install`
```

> ember-cli: 2.14.2
>
> node: 6.11.2
>
> os: win32 x64

I'm new in Ember,Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, did you run `npm install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run `npm install`. If this doesn't help use:

```
ember new new-application
```

To create new application with correct configuration.

Answer (score 0):

After creating project go to your project folder using cd command then hit ember serve.

```
"C:\Users\Documents\emberjs\Your Project Name"> ember serve
```